# "No matching distribution found for sqlite3" with python3 and virtualenv

Tags: python, sqlite, debian, virtualenv

I'm trying to install sqlite3 on Debian 9 using virtualenv and python3.

I'm getting the Error message below:

[Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for sqlite3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c89WD.png)

The "pip list" command returned the following packages

`pip list`

astroid           2.2.0
colorama          0.4.1
coremltools       2.1.0
isort             4.3.9
lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1
mccabe            0.6.1
numpy             1.16.2 
pandas            0.24.1 
pathlib           1.0.1
pip               19.0.3 
pkg-resources     0.0.0
prettytable       0.7.2
protobuf          3.6.1
pylint            2.3.0
python-dateutil   2.8.0
pytz              2018.9 
setuptools        40.8.0 
six               1.12.0 
typed-ast         1.2.0
wheel             0.33.1 
wrapt             1.11.1

System configuration and software version:

Python -V: Python 3.5.3

virtualenv --version: 15.1.0

lsb_release -a:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)
Release:        9.8
Codename:       stretch

I already did some research on this issue but without success.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite3` is a module from [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), you don't need to install it separately.

Comment: Thank you PhD, but I have a situation where I can connect to the DB in the SQLite console but not by my python script. The message returned from my connect function says it is connected, but the returns from the requested query not.

Comment: Well, if the module imported and connects to the DB you certainly don't need to install it. Other problems require separate questions with more details — code and example of a DB (SQL dump).

Comment: The Vscode is giving me the following error message: Missing module docstringpylint(missing-docstring), Unable to import 'sqlite3'pylint(import-error). I isolated a piece of code just to check the connection.

Comment: Thank you phd. I'm using Vim now and it is working fine!